# Intersection of (Interior of a set) and another set versus Interior of Intersection of two sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am using Efe Ok's Real Analysis textbook for self-study. Question 10 in Chapter C asks one to prove that for a metric space $X$ and a metric subspace $Y$ of $X$, for a set $S \subseteq X$, that

$$int_X(S) \cap Y \subseteq int_Y(S \cap Y),$$

where $int_Z$ means "interior with respect to $Z$".

The textbook tells me the converse does not hold in general (though it does hold for open $Y$).

I am confused by this question, as I think I have found a counter-example: 
let $S$, $Y$ be closed sets and $S \not\subset Y$. Then, the interior of $S$ with respect to $X$ is simply $S \setminus bn(S)$, where I denote by $bn(Z)$ the boundary of some set $Z$. The intersection of the (interior of S) and Y is hence:

$$int_X(S) \cap Y = (S \cap Y) \setminus bn(S), $$ right?

While

$$int_Y(S \cap Y) = (S \cap Y) \setminus (bn(S) \cup bn(Y)). $$

Clearly, there can be an example in which the second is strictly smaller than the first. E.g., $Y = [1,5]$, $S= [4,7]$, then $int_X(S) \cap Y = (4,7) \cap [1,5] = (4,5] \not\subset (4,5)$.

But $ int_Y(S \cap Y) = int_Y([4,5]) = (4,5).$

Can someone tell me if I have made a silly mistake (and then suggest a proof?), or can assure me that there is simply a typo in the textbook?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The interior of $[4,5]$ **in the space** $Y=[1,5]$ is $(4,5]$, not $(4,5)$: $(4,5]$ is an open nbhd of $5$ in the space $Y$. (E.g., it’s $Y\cap(4,6)$, where $(4,6)$ is certainly open in $\Bbb R$.) Thus, your example isn’t a counterexample after all.

To show that $(\operatorname{int}_XS)\cap Y\subseteq\operatorname{int}_Y(S\cap Y)$, note that $\operatorname{int}_XS$ is open in $X$, so its intersection with $Y$ is open in $Y$. Moreover, it’s clear that $(\operatorname{int}_XS)\cap Y\subseteq S\cap Y$. Thus, $\operatorname{int}_XS$ is an open subset of $S\cap Y$ and hence by definition is a subset of $\operatorname{int}_Y(S\cap Y)$.

To show that it’s possible to have $(\operatorname{int}_XS)\cap Y\subsetneqq S\cap Y$, take $X=\Bbb R$ and $S=Y=\Bbb Q$: then

$$(\operatorname{int}_X)\cap Y=\varnothing\cap Y=\varnothing\;,$$

but

$$\operatorname{int}_Y(S\cap Y)=\operatorname{int}_YY=Y\ne\varnothing\;.$$

Comment: Thanks a lot!

I now understand where I went wrong and I think I understand the proof and the counterexample to $int_X S \cap Y = int(S \cap Y)$.

However, I am slightly confused by the throwaway comment you make:
"(E.g., it’s $Y\cap(4,6)$, where $(4,6)$ is certainly open in R.)"

Comment: @JM92: You’re welcome!